# Android POS system and hardware go to homescreen via usb

Tags: android, pos

I have an Android hardware POS system but once I turn it on it automatically opens the POS application. There are no navigation buttons (no hardware and no overlaid buttons) so I can't get to the homescreen. Within the app there is an option to open the WiFi Fragment within the Settings app but that's all.

The device also has a printer built-in.

The hardware device does have 2 USB-A connections. How would I get to the homescreen with the use of a computer? I have an USB-A Male to Male cable to connect the device to my computer but how should I make the approach to get to the homescreen?

Here are the pictures of the device:
[image: side]
[image: front]
[image: back]
[image: bottom]

Comment: If there is no information such as vendor, model number, specifications, SDK, etc., only those who can judge by looking at the pictures will be able to react. For example, if the system is customized in the OEM model, only the supernatural powers will be able to identify something from the state where the screen is not displayed. Please refer to the help article to improve your question. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possibly this device was locked by using special tools so that user can only use given POS application